# How do I add a column to my dataframe which indicates datemodified minus 1 month of a file in os directory?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I have a dataframe called temp

```
temp
Partner Zip Phone
VIP     002 267...
```

I have a script that goes through my os directory and adds data to these columns
I wanted a new column called FileMonth where if lets say a file was dropped in the directory today 7/9/2022, the file month should indicate DateModified minus 1 month. in this case June(MM-YYYY)

```
Partner Zip Phone FileMonth
VIP     002 267.. 06-2022
```

Im currently doing-

```
temp['File Month'] = (dt.replace(day=1)-pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime("%m-%Y")
```

But since this is not based on datemodified in os directory, im getting most recent month for all files, which shouldnt be the case since some files were dropped in os even in april and may.
How do I get temp['File Month'] to be the datemodified - 1 month as per directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of file paths you can invoke `os.path.getmtime()` to obtain the timestamp (in seconds) at which the file was last modified. `.replace(month = ...)` allows you to decrease the date's month by one.

The code is given by

```
    import os
    from datetime import datetime
    
    dateModList = []
    for filePath in filePathList:
        ts_mod   = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filePath))
        # properly decrement month (incl. January)
        ts_mod   = ts_mod.replace(month = 12 if ts_mod.month==1 else ts_mod.month-1) 
        ts_mod   = ts_mod.replace(year=ts_mod.year-1 if ts_mod.month==12 else ts_mod.year)   
        date_mod = datetime.strftime(ts_mod, '%m-%Y') 
     
        dateModList.append(date_mod)
    
    # assign column
    temp['File Month'] = dateModList
```

Comment: can this be based on filename instead of entire directory filepath? for example, the beginning of my code looks for a filename within the directory.my code -  for file in os.listdir("//data-share/jobs/ Member Lists"):
    if file.startswith("TVC")and "(updated headers)" not in file:

Comment: instead of filepath which i already have defined in os.listdir("//data-share/jobs/ Member Lists"). can it be based on filename

Comment: You need to locate the file. Defining the file directory `fileDir` and appending the string with the `fileName` will do the trick, e.g. by the list comphrension`filePathList = [fileDir + '/' + fileName for fileName in fileNameList]` Let me know if the answer is sufficient or how to improve the post. Tahnk you.

Comment: Im marking this answer correct as it works for all files within a directory. im framing a new question and will post the link because i feel the list comprehension will be slightly different since i dont use these variables. will post the link to the question here and will give you credit in the new question for part of your code that i need to implement. Feel free to answer that one too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72923073/how-do-i-get-datetime-of-file-in-a-directory-based-on-datemodified-in-python

Comment: Hi @7shoe. i used your code but i am getting an error now after i assign to column  raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: That is unfortunate. You didn't provide any information on the dataframe `temp`. The code above tacitly assumes that the number of files (i.e. `len(filePathList)`) is the same as the number of rows in your dataframe `len(temp)`. A special case where it always works is only if the `filePathList` has length `1`, though.  I have the suspicion that they do not coincide, in general for your use case. Again, pure speculation but also unrelated to the original problem.

Comment: apologies. temp is just a dataframe with about 57 rows and 13 columns temp
Out[18]: 
   MemberNo  ... Date Removed
0    1759-1  ...   2022-03-07
1    2210-1  ...   2022-03-15

Comment: dateModList
Out[17]: ['03-2022'] the output is as expected. but could it be that i get the error because of the [' '] ?. i only want the column to have 03-2022 for all 50 rows of the File Month column

Comment: len(temp)
Out[19]: 57

Comment: len(filePathList) is 43

Comment: any work around for this 7shoe? i only want the File month column to have all rows showing 03-2022

Comment: I cannot remote debug without further information on what you try to achieve. Your two posts suggest that each row in the dataframe coincides with 1 file in the `filePathList`. `temp['File Month']  = '03-2022'` achieves your requirement. But why did we scan files to begin with then...

Comment: the file month changes every month based on date modified of new files. thats why i cant just set temp['File Month']  = '03-2022' permanently. what other info can i provide. please let me know